# Writing functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am new to PostgreSQL and seeking help to write functions in PostgreSQL.
I have following sql queries

1. `Select * from Table1 where col1=x`
2. `Select sum(T1.col1), T2.col2 from Table1 T1, Table2 T2 where T1.col1=T2.col1 and T1.col3= y`

I want to write a function where I will pass the parameteers `(x, y)` and the above queries should come in the output table. I am able to run the function with single query.

I want to run both of these queries in a single function.

Comment: You can't return more than one result set from a function.

Answer (score 0):

If those two result are independent you better create separated functions.

If those are related then you could create a `customType` and make your function return a `set of customType`

```
CREATE TYPE custom_type AS
   (T1_int1 integer,
    T1_int2 integer,
    T2.sum  integer,
    T2.col2 integer
ALTER TYPE custom_type 
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Then you create your function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYFUNCTION(x numeric, y numeric)
RETURNS setof custom_type AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    sRow custom_type ;
BEGIN

    SELECT T1_int1, T1_int2, T2.sum, T2.col2 into sRow 
    FROM 
        TABLE1 something join TABLE2 -- here i need to know more about your schema

    RETURN sRow;
END;
$BODY$
```

More info [Return more than one row of data from PL/pgSQL functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions)